# SQL Join table does not display results in SQL FIddle

Tags: sql

I am trying to complete a project for school and the last step has me do a complex join between all of my tables. I have been going over this so many times, but I can't understand why it won't display the table when I run the SQL. Any help would be awesome.

[image: SQL Join Table]

Comment: I mean, at this point, why not link to the actual sqlfiddle instead of an image of it?

Comment: post the image of a sqlfiddle ????

Comment: You aren't inserting any records into your `SalesOrder` table.. What do you expect to return?

Comment: SalesOrder needs to join on Customer Id , SalesOrder Id is an incremented Identity Primary key value and does not match the donutId value in the table you are trying to join it to, OrderLine

Comment: your 2nd on clause should join on ORDERID twice not donutID. and as there are no records in salesorder, no records will be returned as Aaron pointed out)  both errors must be fixed for data to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join to test if system is able to find any record.

add left join instead of join so you can see where you are missing data it might possible that system was not able to find records from sub table that's why its empty.